# Force clear Cache of web site

Tags: php, caching

I'm trying to clear the cache of my site when a certain button is pressed. I have put the following in an if statement however I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop. Not sure why? Here's what I'm echoing within my if statement:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; mywebsitetest.org/ \" />";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"pragma\" content=\"no-cache\">";
echo "<script type=" . "text/javascript" . ">";
echo "window.location.replace('mywebsitetest.org') </script>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean, printing these strings is causing infinite loop?

Comment: Why are you looping through it and not just echoing it out once when a condition has been met?

Comment: since echoing those strings, the page gets stuck in an infinte loops

Comment: Of course it does, what did you expect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; mywebsitetest.org/ " />
```

refreshes the page in 0 seconds.

```javascript
window.location.replace('mywebsitetest.org')
```

also refreshes the page on load.

If your conditions remain true after reloading, you are stuck in an infinite refreshing loop.